# Sorting Parent-Child with orderby linq

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Input:

[image]

I want to develop linq query order by job name(parents) and sequence of child with in list of object

i tried below query (not working)

```
qry = qry.OrderBy(j => j.Id).ThenBy(j => j.jobName).ThenBy(j => j.documentGroupId);
```

Expected Output:

[image]

Any one help!!!

Comment: Add ToList() list after  Query qry = qry.OrderBy(j => j.Id).ThenBy(j => j.jobName).ThenBy(j => j.documentGroupId).ToList();

Comment: can you explain more about the columns?

Comment: No, i just tried with my knowledge

Comment: Please read [the accepted answer to "Why not upload images...?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the expected result is ordering by ID column first, but from 1004 to 1001 which means you need to order it by descending. Use [Enumerbale.OrderByDescending](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Enumerable.ThenByDescending](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534489(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

You should try that:

```
var result = qry.OrderByDescending(j => j.Id).
          ThenBy(j => j.SubId).
          ThenBy(j => j.JobName).
          ThenByDescending(j => j.DocumentGroupId).ToList();
```

Also, it would be great to have more details on how things should be sorted. Not just expected result screen.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
qry =
  qry
    .GroupBy(j => j.Id)
    .OrderBy(group => group
      .Single(j => j.SubId == 0)
      .Name)
    .SelectMany(group => group
      .OrderBy(j => j.SubId))
    .ToList();
```